# Trying to setup device-to-device notifications via FCM; any recommendation when it comes to FCM and choosing XMPP server?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I read the documentation for FCM in Firebase website, looked into answers here for related questions and googled. All good, but as a newbie I am not sure what's best approach when it comes in choosing the XMPP server.

Is there anything that would limit one of the servers in the list blow when it comes to connecting to FCM? I have a list of servers [here](https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html).

Should I choose one of the servers in this list for FCM if I need device to device notifications or is there any other choice. I need it for when a new message arrives in a chat app or similar cases when a `ChildAdded` or modified and the app is backgrounded or closed?

I cannot find any info on the XMPP servers and if Firebase has any recommendation. I would need all three iOS, Android, and Web app support.

Comment: It depends what kind of notification you wanted to send and also how much data you want to transfer as notification payload. If your requirement is to just wake-up some kind of service in device, better to use simple http. Also, you might consider using MQTT (device efficient)in case you need persistence connection. For XMPP, you can use any of the listed servers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , I have learned that google other products can do the job most likely. For example google App Engine seems to be able to play the app server role in this case.